# Training different objects using tensorflow Object detection API

Tags: tensorflow

I recently came across this link for learning tensorflow object detection
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rgpfk6eYxJA&t=993s
However I have few doubts and want suggestion on how to proceed.
1) How should I train different objects using the same model( I mean what should my data set contain if I want to train cats,dogs as objects.
2) and once I have trained it for dogs and then continue training on cars will the model detect dogs?

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset should contain a large variety of examples for every object (class) you wish to detect. It sounds like you're misunderstanding the training process by assuming that you train it on each class of objects in sequence, this is incorrect. When you train the model you will be taking a random batch of samples (maybe 64 for example) across all classes.

Training simultaneously on all or many of the classes makes sense, you have one model that has to perform equally well on all classes. So when you train the model you compute the error of the parameters with respect to a random selection of classes and average the error to come up with each update step, yielding a model that performs well across classes.

Notice that it's quite common to run into class imbalance issues. If you have only a few samples of cats, and millions of samples of dogs you will disproportionately penalize the network for misclassifying dogs as cats and the network will simply always predict dog to hedge its bet. Ideally, you will have a roughly equal balance of data per class, if not, there are books and tutorials galore on the strategies to deal with this.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me I will look into it and get back to you if I have a doubt!